# Firebase Crash.. iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

My Firebase iOS App i had to put the frameworks in manually due to some reason in cocoapods.

i have been getting an crash error saying

```
2016-06-04 00:48:51.356 NewFirebase[74218:11918327] Configuring the default app.
2016-06-04 00:48:51.401 NewFirebase[74218:11918425] +[NSData gtm_dataByGzippingData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10bdd8110
2016-06-04 00:48:51.403 NewFirebase[74218:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
2016-06-04 00:48:51.404 NewFirebase[74218:11918425] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSData gtm_dataByGzipping
```

The only line i have put related to firebase is

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        FIRApp.configure()


        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                                                              didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        return true
    }
```

other is related to facebook login i am gonna put with firebase

These are the frameworks in it
[image: Frameworks]

This is what the linker section looks like in the build settings
[image: Linker Flags Section]

Please feel free if you want any more code

if i get rid of `FIRApp.configure()` Everything works fine as its supposed to be ..

Comment: Did you download and add a GoogleService-Info property list from console.firebase.google.com?

Comment: Hey, you're doing better than me: 101 linker errors.  I followed the instructions in the README, which say they are for Xcode 7.

Comment: I am running into the same problem. It seems like Google's documentation is incomplete. I've chosen not to use CocoaPods, am importing all of the libraries, and have set the -Objc "Other Linker Flag". Still crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 targeting iOS 9.3 on OS X 10.11.5.

I had the exact same issue as above with the "Undefined symbols" issue.

I first emptied everything from the "Other Linker Flags" and then added $(OTHER_LDFLAGS) and -ObjC as 2 separate items (using the + button when you double click).

The other thing I did was remove the frameworks giving me issues - GoogleUtilities and FirebaseAnalytics.

I then added them back in using the "Add files to Project" option one at a time and ensured they are targeted to my iOS app.

The build was successful after that and ads show up.

Comment: Thanks, solve my problem too! I have added 3 lines $(inherited) $(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC

Answer (score 15):

You need to add these libraries

- libc++.tbd
- libsqlite3.tbd
- AddressBook.framework

to **Link Binary With Libraries**.

Go to Targets -> Build Phases

[image]

Comment: I also had to add `libz.tbd` in addition to the ones above.

Comment: This fixed the build for me. How come it's not in the set up instructions? A very cryptic error message too.

Answer (score 7):

add two parameter in Other Linker Flags

```
$(inherited)
-ObjC
```

[image]

Comment: The `Getting Started Guide` links to what the op used, and the `framework SDK`'s  README says to merely use `-ObjC`.

Comment: See answer below.,,,,I've successfully created a Firebase app with CocoaPods, but following the framework setup didn't work for me. `Xcode 7.2.1/iOS 9.2/Swift 2.1.1/OSX 10.10.5`

Answer (score 3):

I just lost hours to this  - the readme and documentation is really poor

You also need to include the GoogleToolboxForMac.framework I missed this out as I assumed it was for mac apps, but adding it in fixed the problem.

Comment: You saved my day, i thought the same thing and this solved it

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Answer for comment above:

Edit: Here is what my `Build Settings` look like:

The README.md in the Firebase directory said to drag the `Firebase.h` file into the project, as well as the `module.modulemap` file and add the path to the module.modulemap file to the `User Header Search Paths`:
[image]

The README.md in the Firebase directory said to enter merely `-ObjC` here:
[image]

Here is what my `Project Navigator` looks like:
[image]

```
Ld /Users/7stud/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirebaseApplicationExample-ewixbbawksqkuaaqeeobeaexeirc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseApplicationExample.app/FirebaseApplicationExample normal x86_64
    cd /Users/7stud/xcode_projects/iOS/FirebaseApplicationExample
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.2
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/7stud/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirebaseApplicationExample-ewixbbawksqkuaaqeeobeaexeirc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/7stud/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirebaseApplicationExample-ewixbbawksqkuaaqeeobeaexeirc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/7stud/xcode_projects/iOS/FirebaseApplicationExample/FirebaseApplicationExample -filelist /Users/7stud/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirebaseApplicationExample-ewixbbawksqkuaaqeeobeaexeirc/Build/Intermediates/FirebaseApplicationExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseApplicationExample.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FirebaseApplicationExample.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.2 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/7stud/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirebaseApplicationExample-ewixbbawksqkuaaqeeobeaexeirc/Build/Intermediates/FirebaseApplicationExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseApplicationExample.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FirebaseApplicationExample.swiftmodule -framework FirebaseDatabase -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleUtilities -framework FirebaseInstanceID -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/7stud/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirebaseApplicationExample-ewixbbawksqkuaaqeeobeaexeirc/Build/Intermediates/FirebaseApplicationExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseApplicationExample.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FirebaseApplicationExample_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/7stud/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirebaseApplicationExample-ewixbbawksqkuaaqeeobeaexeirc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseApplicationExample.app/FirebaseApplicationExample

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ABAddressBookAddRecord", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABAddressBook addRecord:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABAddressBook groups] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABAddressBook people] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel", referenced from:
      +[GSDK_GTMABAddressBook localizedLabel:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABAddressBook peopleWithCompositeNameWithPrefix:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABAddressBook init] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABAddressBook groupForId:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABAddressBook personForId:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABAddressBook hasUnsavedChanges] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookRemoveRecord", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABAddressBook removeRecord:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookSave", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABAddressBook save] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABGroupAddMember", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABGroup addMember:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABGroup members] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABGroupCreate", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABGroup init] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABGroupRemoveMember", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABGroup removeMember:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABMutableMultiValue addValue:withLabel:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABMultiValue labelAtIndex:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
      -[GSDK_GTMABMultiValueEnumerator nextObject] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABMultiValue valueAtIndex:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueCreateMutable", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABMutableMultiValue initWithPropertyType:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABMutableMultiValue initWithMultiValue:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueGetCount", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABMultiValue count] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABMultiValue identifierAtIndex:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABMultiValue indexForIdentifier:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueGetPropertyType", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABMultiValue propertyType] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueInsertValueAndLabelAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABMutableMultiValue insertValue:withLabel:atIndex:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueRemoveValueAndLabelAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABMutableMultiValue removeValueAndLabelAtIndex:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueReplaceLabelAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABMutableMultiValue replaceLabelAtIndex:withLabel:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueReplaceValueAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABMutableMultiValue replaceValueAtIndex:withValue:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABPersonCopyImageData", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABPerson imageData] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABPersonCopyLocalizedPropertyName", referenced from:
      +[GSDK_GTMABPerson localizedPropertyName:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABPersonCreate", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABPerson init] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat", referenced from:
      +[GSDK_GTMABPerson compositeNameFormat] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABPersonGetTypeOfProperty", referenced from:
      +[GSDK_GTMABPerson typeOfProperty:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABPersonRemoveImageData", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABPerson setImageData:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABPersonSetImageData", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABPerson setImageData:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABRecordCopyCompositeName", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABPerson compositeName] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
      -[GSDK_GTMABGroup compositeName] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABRecordCopyValue", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABRecord valueForProperty:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABRecordGetRecordID", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABRecord recordID] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABRecordRemoveValue", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABRecord removeValueForProperty:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "_ABRecordSetValue", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMABRecord setValue:forProperty:] in GoogleUtilities(GTMABAddressBook.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const", referenced from:
      leveldb::VersionSet::Recover() in FirebaseDatabase(version_set.o)
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<int, leveldb::FileMetaData>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<int, leveldb::FileMetaData> > >::__push_back_slow_path<std::__1::pair<int, leveldb::FileMetaData> const>(std::__1::pair<int, leveldb::FileMetaData> const&) in FirebaseDatabase(db_impl.o)
      void std::__1::vector<unsigned long long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long long> >::__push_back_slow_path<unsigned long long const>(unsigned long long const&) in FirebaseDatabase(db_impl.o)
      void std::__1::vector<leveldb::DBImpl::CompactionState::Output, std::__1::allocator<leveldb::DBImpl::CompactionState::Output> >::__push_back_slow_path<leveldb::DBImpl::CompactionState::Output const>(leveldb::DBImpl::CompactionState::Output const&) in FirebaseDatabase(db_impl.o)
      void std::__1::vector<leveldb::Iterator*, std::__1::allocator<leveldb::Iterator*> >::__push_back_slow_path<leveldb::Iterator* const>(leveldb::Iterator* const&) in FirebaseDatabase(db_impl.o)
...
...
      "_utf8_nextCharSafeBody", referenced from:
          -[FSRWebSocket _innerPumpScanner] in FirebaseDatabase(FSRWebSocket.o)
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    Showing first 200 notices only
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this linker flag fixed the problem for me. I had tried using CocoaPods first, but couldn't get it to import any of the more specific Firebase modules.  Adding the frameworks directly worked, but only if the -ObjC linker flag was added.

Answer (score 0):

I was just dragging code files and frameworks from another project and encountered this problem.
After adding all frameworks in build phase, adding -ObjC in 'other linker flags' solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by removing **FirebaseNanoPB** and **FirebaseCoreDiagnostics** framework from my project.

Comment: I have been struggling with this issue for 6 weeks. I have tried dozens and dozens of suggestions: I of course set the ObjC flag (like everyone suggested a million times across numerous StackOverflow threads), I added and removed various frameworks, recreated my project from scratch in case I had a corrupted workspace, moved away from pods and manually installed all my frameworks. Turns out I just needed to remove these two frameworks in addition to Analytics (since it depends on them). Thank you for your suggestion.