# FireBase-Analytics IOS

Tags: ios, firebase-analytics

## i'm new mobile developer, today i add firebase analytics framework in my project using code [FIRApp configure], so when i running app, the app be crash.Someone can help me fix this bug? Thanks all! Here's log in xcode:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSData gtm_dataByGzippingData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1a0c5a8b8'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1834f9900 0x182b67f80 0x183500514 0x1834fd5b8 0x18340168c 0x1001cda2c 0x1001e17c8 0x1001e13b8 0x1012d1bf0 0x1012d1bb0 0x1012de6c8 0x1012d58a0 0x1012d1bb0 0x1012e0e10 0x1012e04d8 0x183161470 0x183161020)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Could you provide more information about your setup? Which library version are you using? Are you using cocoapods to add Firebase to your project?

Comment: i add all frame work in FireBase-Analytics, there is lastest version i download from https://dl.google.com/firebase/sdk/ios/3_3_0/Firebase.zip, i'm using firebase without cocoapods. All step in file ReadMe i done but can't fix this bug. Here is framework i added: FirebaseInstanceID.framework
GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework
GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework
GoogleUtilities.framework                                   FirebaseAnalytics.framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Crash.. iOS Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625029/firebase-crash-ios-swift)

Answer (score 3):

Please download the latest zip file. I had similar crash when I forgot to add the linker flag **-ObjC**. Are you by any chance missing that flag:

> 7. Add the -ObjC flag to "Other Linker Settings":   a. In your project settings, open the Settings panel for your target   b. Go to the Build
>      Settings tab and find the "Other Linking Flags" setting
>       in the Linking section.   c. Double-click the setting, click the '+' button, and add "-ObjC" (without quotes)

Here is where it should be[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWPgE.png)

Comment: Wow thanks man - that was it for me! I accidently only set this flag to the release scheme and not the debug