# Firebase error while configuring app - unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I'm using Firebase in an iOS app and have two separate Firebase projects, one for production and one for development. My two .plist files are `GoogleService-Info.plist` and `GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist`, which I have been able to select based on a flag set in Targets -> Build Settings -> Other Swift Flags.

Inside AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
#if DEBUG
    let buildFor = "DEV"
#else
    let buildFor = "PROD"
#endif
let firebasePlistFileName = buildFor == "DEV" ? "GoogleService-Info-Dev" : "GoogleService-Info"
let firebaseOptions = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(firebasePlistFileName, ofType: "plist"))
FIRApp.configureWithOptions(firebaseOptions) // line causing new Firebase error
```

This has been working fine up until today, when I had a problem with another Cocoapod project. I think it started happening when I cleaned the Xcode project or deleted Derived Data folder:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/OtherPod.framework/OtherPod
  Referenced from:
  /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/12345678-E1C4-480F-B1D9-C10823DEA810/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/AE7B6EB0-43AB-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA71BF/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Reason: image not found
```

I eventually resolved that by choosing my app under Targets -> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries, then added all of the choices inside the `Workspace` folder (7 other pod projects) and set those ones I added as optional. Ever since then, I've been facing the error described in the title of this post:

```
2017-02-10 17:19:29.660 MyApp[12639:182433] +[NSData gtm_dataByGzippingData:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10a0442e8
2017-02-10 17:19:29.680 MyApp[12639:182433] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSData gtm_dataByGzippingData:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10a0442e8'
*** First throw call stack:
(
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d88d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001097f121e objc_exception_throw + 48
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109df8e44 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
  3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d0e005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
  4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d0db88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
  5   MyApp                               0x0000000102d73c9d -[FIRNetwork postURL:payload:queue:usingBackgroundSession:completionHandler:] + 331
  6   MyApp                               0x0000000102d70e72 -[FIRClearcutLogger sendNextPendingRequestWithCompletionHandler:] + 570
  7   MyApp                               0x0000000102d70918 -[FIRClearcutLogger sendLogsWithCompletionHandler:] + 447
  8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a6ab978 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
  9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a6d50cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
  10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a6b2e17 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
  11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a6b3b4b _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
  12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a6b402b _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 683
  13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a6b6385 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
  14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a6b6059 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
  15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010aa3a712 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
  16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010aa3a1ed start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have tried a lot of different fixes, including [adding to the Link Binary with Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082857/772985), [adding to the Other Linker Flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37627693/772985), and none of them have worked.

What could the unrecognized selector possibly be, and how would I change/remove it? Could this issue be due to the earlier one I was facing (library not loaded)?

For clarification, when the `unrecognized selector sent to class` error happens, the Xcode debug navigator is focused on Thread 7, with the `FIRApp.configureWithOptions(firebaseOptions)` line being highlighted.

**Update**

I found a temporary fix by reverting to a previous git commit (cloned my repository into a separate directory), then replacing the majority of the project contents from that old commit with the current error-producing copy, including the *App-Name* folder within root directory, *App-Name*.xcodeproj, and *App-Name*.xcworkspace. I only tested on the simulator (iPhone 7 running iOS 10.2), and that worked. I then successfully submitted a build to iTunes Connect and was able to run that build on my device (iPhone 5c with 10.2.1), but after deleting that and attempting to run a build from Xcode, I got the same error again. However, the error **did not** occur while running on the simulator. This is in contrast to the initial error scenario as it occurred on both physical device and simulator.

This made me remember that the stack trace I initially posted was that of running the app on the simulator. Running it on the device produced less output, specifically the content after `*** First throw call stack:` is only `(0x1d01cdf7 0x1c27f077 0x1d022467 0x1d020579 0x1cf453d8 0x31ff3f 0x31d653 0x31d05d 0x1c57d57 0x1c63e63 0x1c5b205 0x1c64391 0x1c65d9f 0x1c65ba7 0x1c877937 0x1c877490)` instead of the more descriptive output with file/function names.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Earlier, I have faced the same issue, I fixed the issue by reinstalling `pod`.

Please refer to the below-mentioned steps to resolve the issue.

Please make sure that you have added Add two-parameter in `Other Linker Flags.`

```
$(inherited)
-ObjC
```

## Cocoapods:

Just install cocoa-pods again in the project. Please refer below command for remove and install pods.

**Remove all Framework from project using below command.**

```
pod deintegrate
pod clean
```

**- Install framework using below pod command**

```
pod install
```

## Manual:

If you have added `framework` Manual in the project then remove it and add it into the project again.

## Issue:

> You have faced reference issue in your project (`framework` not found at
>   Specific Directory).

**Hit the Clean and Build project. Everything worked as expected**

Comment: This did the trick. The two parameters `$(inherited)` and `-ObjC` were already in my `Other Linker Flags` section, along with 80-100 other lines (half of them -framework). pod deintegrate worked, but pod clean seems to be an unknown command (my pod --version is 1.2.0). I still went through with pod install, clean and build, and no longer got the error.

Comment: Glad to hear @SergeyMolyak

Comment: Thanks a lot. But 'pod clean' was 'pod cache clean --all' in my case

Comment: Helped me with a non cocoapods problem. I was having this exception `FIRInstanceIDCheckinPreferences preferencesFromKeychainContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to class`

Answer (score 4):

Make sure GTMNSData+zlib.m from the GoogleToolboxForMac pod is still being built and linked into your app.

[image]

Make sure that -ObjC and -framework GoogleToolboxForMac is in the Link log:

[image]

Comment: GTMNSData+zlib.m is already under Compile Sources for me, with what looks to be the same compiler flags that you have in the screenshot as well (-DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0).

Comment: Hmm, maybe your xcode environment is corrupted. Some options would be regenerating your .xcworkspace file, build cleaning, and/or removing DerivedData. Also, you could try editing the GTMNSData+zlib.m with a syntax error and making sure it gets rebuilt. If none of that works, you could copy gtm_dataByGzippingBytes to a place in your app that is definitely being built.

Comment: Editing the file with a syntax error does cause the build to fail, and removing the error allows the build but the same runtime error still occurs. If I were to copy that function to somewhere else in my app that is being built, where would I do it if gtm_dataByGzippingData is an Objective-C function while my project is in Swift? And to regenerate the .xcworkspace file, do I just need to delete then then run pod install?

Comment: Yes, to regenerate the .xcworkspace file, delete it, and run pod install.  Also make sure -ObjC is set in your project's Build Settings under "Other Linker Flags".

Comment: Still no luck, deleting it and running pod install has the same outcome as before

Comment: Added a screenshot to the answer with a few more things to check

Comment: In your screenshot I am assuming it is the output from the Link task underneath 'Build Target AppName' and not one of the 'Build Target Pod/Other Library'. -ObjC and -framework GoogleToolboxForMac are both in the Link log, however, -ObjC appears 5 separate times, and -framework GoogleToolboxForMac appears 3 times while weak_framework GoogleToolboxForMac appears once. Maybe those repeats indicate something that's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone experiencing this problem, while trying to add the firebase frameworks manually. I had the same issue, which was caused by having different versions of firebase. I tried to add additional frameworks as the readme suggested, but experienced the above mentioned error.

I resolved this by removing all the firebase frameworks from the project and build phases. Downloaded the newest version, and re-added all frameworks to the project, and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I just typed `pod update` and then closed out and reopened Xcode afterward. Worked for me.