# firebase configuration crash

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Firebase crashes when execute `firebase.configure` I have multiple targets in workspace

```
    #if Client
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    #else
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-xxx", ofType: "plist")!
    let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: options!)
    #endif
```

I know the problem is from `GoogleService-Info.plist` file.
My `Client` target works fine, but my other target crashes on line  `FirebaseApp.configure(options: options!)`
  I have debugged it and the options of the  `GoogleService-Info-xxx` is there .

Crash log :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[FIRInstanceIDCheckinPreferences preferencesFromKeychainContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1035b7d60'

Comment: You should not need to add the options programmatically. Just place the `GoogleService-Info.plist` in the `Resources` group and call `FirebaseApp.configure()`

Comment: and how Firebase would know which file to configure considering there are multiple targets ?

Comment: Select the file, and on the right side inspector, you can check which targets to apply the file to

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169907/firebase-error-while-configuring-app-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to explicitly specify options during configuration. As shown in the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup/) you should only need to call `Firebase.configure()` in your app's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method after you have correctly imported your configuration file as instructed in [Step 3](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup/#add-config-file). If you have multiple build targets simply select the configuration file after you added it to your project, and in the File Inspector, check the box(es) next to the target(s) you want to have the configuration file bundled with.

Comment: I did check the boxes for targets, but as i know firebase looks for the same file name and xworckspace can't have 2 files with the same nam, and that creates the problem for example firebase looking for xxxxx.plist, i can't have two files with that name

Comment: Xcode should copy the same file to both bundles if you have them checked under target assignment. Is one bundle nested within the other? This is a pretty straightforward process so I will need more information from you to help